# Python - using a string in for in statement?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, expression

so i know this is a bit of a workaround and theres probably a better way to do this, but heres the deal. Ive simplified the code from where tis gathering this info from and just given solid values.

```
curSel = nuke.selectedNodes()
knobToChange = "label"
codeIn = "[value in]"

kcPrefix = "x"
kcStart = "['"
kcEnd = "']"

changerString = kcPrefix+kcStart+knobToChange+kcEnd


for x in curSel:
    changerString.setValue(codeIn)
```

But i get the error i figured i would - which is that a string has no attribute "setValue"

its because if i just type x['label'] instead of changerString, it works, but even though changer string says the exact same thing, its being read as a string instead of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be able to do `for x in curSel:` then `for key, value in enumerate(x):` ... Could you give some examples of curSel values?

Comment: sorry can you explain? not getting that

Comment: Why would you want to set a single string's value to the same thing *n* times anyway? What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Its not a single item... im ina  program with Many nodes selected and a for loop is how you cycle through to change everything in this. I want to change multiple to this same value beacuse [value in' (which is what im changing it to) will affect each item differently.

Comment: do you literally want to put `[value in]` in each node's label slot, or am I misreading this?

Comment: `changerString` is a single variable. Anything you could do to mutate it (which, in this case, is nothing, since it's immutable) the way you're trying to would just end up doing the exact same thing a bunch of times.

Comment: For context (incase people were wondering) the piece of software here is Nuke and it's a node based piece of compositing software. The square brackets are Nuke's escape sequence to denote tag TCL for evaluation.

Comment: @tanantish -- As I don't know anything about `Nuke`, I'm guessing that OP isn't doing what my answer supposes and I should delete it?

Comment: Tanatish you seem to know whats goiing on. Could you help me out here?

Comment: And yes id want [value in] in each nodes label - thats why im using selections in the beginning, and theres an input text box where value in is allowed to be changed to say [value rotate] or whatever. I want all selected to get whatever code is input placed there. ive done things liek this a million times before but im sleep deprived and cant get this to work lol.

Comment: @mgilson I think your answer is fine, we're both barking up similar trees with our answers, but I don't believe that creating a string and then evaluating it to a python object is the way to go (Nuke exposes the node and knob objects, so string eval is not needed)

Comment: So what do you suggest.... i do this all the time - that is to say this is how i normally work this kind of problem and its always worked, but if theres a better way, please tell me !

Comment: @user1917081 Just from the code fragment you've posted, I don't think there's anything more than just using the python objects directly (as per my answer - there's a setValue() method on the knob object which you can get to). Is there something there i'm missing? (noting that it's 1am here, so also am sleep deprived..)

Comment: Im not sure where either of us are in this issue anymore so ill try and freshen it up. I have 2 items, codeIn  and  knobToChange. knob to change lists the nodes knob name based off user input in a text box, whether it be label, rotate, scale, etc. codeIn is also a user input textbox where they can type [value in] (perhaps on a shuffle for display of what channels its using) or anything else, in the given knob. Im doing this for multiple nodes so im using curSel = nuke.selectedNodes() and running a for loop to effect all of them. the issue is that when i say for x in curSel: my other variables

Comment: never want to read in properly no matter how i code it, and im not sure why because ive done this many times.

Comment: @user1917081 Just taking your original script, and replacing the line in the for loop with my line `x.knob(the_selected_knob).setValue(codeIn)` I can change the knob which is set in `the_selected_knob` to the value set in `codeIn` on all the selected nodes, which sounds like what you're after? If you can provide more detail on what's not reading in properly or a copy of the full script then I might have a better guess?

Comment: the issue i get with that is instead of giving me [value in] under label it comes up saying: Nothing is named "in"   - which is not what id expect, and im not wuite sure whats happening there

Comment: heres the code 
    curSel = nuke.selectedNodes()
    knobToChange = nuke.thisNode()['knobname'].getValue()
    codeIn = nuke.thisNode()['codeinput'].getValue()

    for x in curSel:
        x.knob(knobToChange).setValue(codeIn)
in which the inputs for knobToChange is label and codeIn is [value in]

Comment: Its very strange, is if i change it to this: cStart = "["
cEnd = "]"
codingIn = cStart+codeIn+cEnd

for x in curSel:
 x.knob(knobToChange).setValue(codingIn)

and instead of my input being [value in] its just value in, it works...

Comment: @user1917081 Ah. Right. I know what's happening (basically, Nuke is evaluating the TCL so your getValue() call is getting the result of the TCL call, which is an error message). I forget how to fix it, but will have a quick stab at a few things.

Comment: as i said, i got it fixed by breaking it up... however isnt there a python command something along the lines of nuke.tcl or something? I know you should really avoid mixing the 2 but oh well.

Comment: @user1917081 Righto. Answer updated. Short form - use .toScript(), not getValue(). And yes, there is a `nuke.tcl()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righto, there's two things you're falling afoul of. Firstly, in your original code where you are trying to do the setValue() call on a string you're right in that it won't work. Ideally use one of the two calls (`x.knob('name_of_the_knob')` or `x['name_of_the_knob']`, whichever is consistent with your project/facility/personal style) to get and set the value of the knob object.

From the comments, your code would look like this (my comments added for other people who aren't quite as au fait with Nuke):

```
# select all the nodes
curSel = nuke.selectedNodes() 

# nuke.thisNode() returns the script's context 
# i.e. the node from which the script was invoked
knobToChange = nuke.thisNode()['knobname'].getValue() 
codeIn = nuke.thisNode()['codeinput'].getValue() 

for x in curSel: 
    x.knob(knobToChange).setValue(codeIn)
```

Using this sample UI with the values in the two fields as shown and the button firing off the script...

[image: sample UI with the relevant buttons]

...this code is going to give you an error message of 'Nothing is named "foo"' when you execute it because the `.getValue()` call is actually returning you the *evaluated result* of the knob - which is the error message as it tries to execute the TCL [value foo], and finds that there isn't any object named foo.

What you should ideally do is instead invoke **`.toScript()`** which returns the raw text.

```
# select all the nodes
curSel = nuke.selectedNodes() 

# nuke.thisNode() returns the script's context 
# i.e. the node from which the script was invoked
knobToChange = nuke.thisNode()['knobname'].toScript() 
codeIn = nuke.thisNode()['codeinput'].toScript() 

for x in curSel: 
    x.knob(knobToChange).setValue(codeIn)
```

You can sidestep this problem as you've noted by building up a string, adding in square brackets etc etc as per your original code, but yes, it's a pain, a maintenance nightmare, and starting to go down that route of building objects up from strings (which @mgilson explains how to do in both a `globals()` or `eval()` method)

---

For those who haven't had the joy of working with Nuke, here's a small screencap that may (or may not..) provide more context:

[image: sample screenie from Nuke showing the node graph and the properties dialog box]

Comment: To be clear -- I'm not really encouraging the "build" a string and convert to an object approach (`eval`).  I'm not really even encouraging the "take the object's name and use it to get a handle on the object" approach (`globals`) -- Though that's much better than `eval`.  I'm encouraging the "use a proper data-structure" approach :)

Comment: @mgilson My bad. Rewrote the answer (since we now have a better handle on the issue) and made it a bit clearer you weren't suggesting the globals or eval methods as _good_ ideas :)

Comment: Thanks man this cleans a lot up, and i was unaware of the toScript() command! that will come in very handy.

Comment: it's not exactly jumping out at you from the API reference, but if you know where to look (and make the connection that what you enter in as text knob is called an 'EvalString_Knob' object..) it sorta helps :)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're looking for something to evaluate the string into a python object based on your current namespace.  One way to do that would be to use the `globals` dictionary:

```
globals()['x']['label'].setValue(...)
```

In other words, `globals()['x']['label']` is the same thing as `x['label']`.

Or to spell it out explicitly for your case:

```
globals()[kcPrefix][knobToChange].setValue(codeIn)
```

---

Others might suggest `eval`:

```
eval('x["label"]').setValue(...)  #insecure and inefficient
```

but `globals` is definitely a better idea here.

---

Finally, usually when you want to do something like this, you're better off using a dictionary or some other sort of data structure in the first place to keep your data more organized

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Neither is a good idea in 99% of cases.

Comment: No this wont work , the reason im doing it the other way is its based off fo user input... if i just wanted to type x.['label'] i could so so.

Comment: basically what im saying is it HAS to use changerString to get the x['label'] in there, because label could change to anything, based on user input.

Comment: @user1917081 -- Then why not:  `globals()['x'][user_input].setValue()`?  I'm not sure I understand your constraint ...

Comment: Its not so much a contraint as im new to python and dont understand what glboals is doing.

Comment: `globals` returns the current module's namespace as a dictionary-like object.  So, `print x` and `print globals()['x']` do the exact same thing.

Comment: okay well it got me closer but now my second input doesnt work. if i use globals()['x'][knobToChange].setValue(codeIn) it prints something but not properly, whereas if i run the code sepperate and just say x['label'].setValue([value in]) it works fine. and fyi codeIn = "[value in]" in this case

Comment: @user1917081 -- I edited to spell it out explicitly for your case.

Comment: thanks, appreicated - but i had that much, it jsut seems codeIn doesnt work as it should now as i mentioned above :(

Comment: @user1917081 -- based on a comment above, it appears that you may not be trying to do what I thought you were attempting...

Comment: well its working for the most part - its just that codeIn is one more thing it needs to read - which usually works... anytime i have say... codeIn = [value in] and then say <whatever>.setValue(codeIn) it works fine, here its not doing it though.

Comment: @user1917081 -- Have you looked at the answer by tanantish?  It seems that he/she may understand your problem slightly better than I do as that user seems to have used `nuke` before.

Comment: new to this site and couldnt find an add comment button... my browser had display issues and didnt show the add/show more comments bit =( asking him now